# Ecobee: Response returning only partial results

Tags: json, google-apps-script, ecobee

Using Google Apps script to attempt to talk to my thermostat using the [Ecobee API](https://www.ecobee.com/home/developer/api/examples/ex2.shtml).  In the below code, the value of `json` is `"{ "status": { "code": 0, "message": "" } }"`.  For the correct, full response, see the results of `curl` later in the question.

For some reason `response` is only getting the final element (`status`) out of the three results that are returned by the server (`page`, `thermostatList`, and `status`).

What am I missing?

Google Apps Script is as follows:

```
function getSettings() {
  var response = fetchSettings();
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  // response, json, and data only show `status` result
}

function fetchSettings() {
  try {
    var headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer AUTH_TOKEN'
    };
    var payload = { 
      'selection' : { 
        'selectionType':'registered',
        'selectionMatch': '',
        'includeRuntime': 'true'
      } 
    };

    var options = {
      'method': 'get',
      'headers': headers,
      'contentType': 'text/json',
      'payload': JSON.stringify(payload);
    };
    var URL = 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?format=json'
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL,options);
  } catch(e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

Using `curl` as follows:

```
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: text/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN' 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?format=json&body=\{"selection":\{"selectionType":"registered","selectionMatch":"",includeRuntime":true\}\}'
```

I get full results.

```
{
  "page": {
    "page": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "pageSize": 2,
    "total": 2
  },
  "thermostatList": [
    {
      "identifier": "12345",
      "name": "Downstairs",
      "thermostatRev": "160528163253",
      "isRegistered": true,
      "modelNumber": "athenaSmart",
      "brand": "ecobee",
      "features": "",
      "lastModified": "2016-05-28 16:32:53",
      "thermostatTime": "2016-05-28 11:57:00",
      "utcTime": "2016-05-28 16:57:00",
      "runtime": {
        "runtimeRev": "160528165546",
        "connected": true,
        "firstConnected": "2015-08-20 21:57:53",
        "connectDateTime": "2016-05-26 08:56:18",
        "disconnectDateTime": "2016-05-26 00:00:00",
        "lastModified": "2016-05-28 16:55:46",
        "lastStatusModified": "2016-05-28 16:55:46",
        "runtimeDate": "2016-05-28",
        "runtimeInterval": 200,
        "actualTemperature": 703,
        "actualHumidity": 49,
        "desiredHeat": 670,
        "desiredCool": 810,
        "desiredHumidity": 44,
        "desiredDehumidity": 56,
        "desiredFanMode": "on"
      }
    },
    {
      "identifier": "310166836750",
      "name": "Upstairs",
      "thermostatRev": "160528162656",
      "isRegistered": true,
      "modelNumber": "athenaSmart",
      "brand": "ecobee",
      "features": "",
      "lastModified": "2016-05-28 16:26:56",
      "thermostatTime": "2016-05-28 11:57:00",
      "utcTime": "2016-05-28 16:57:00",
      "runtime": {
        "runtimeRev": "160528165523",
        "connected": true,
        "firstConnected": "2015-09-28 13:33:41",
        "connectDateTime": "2016-05-26 08:55:35",
        "disconnectDateTime": "2016-05-26 00:00:00",
        "lastModified": "2016-05-28 16:55:23",
        "lastStatusModified": "2016-05-28 16:55:23",
        "runtimeDate": "2016-05-28",
        "runtimeInterval": 201,
        "actualTemperature": 712,
        "actualHumidity": 49,
        "desiredHeat": 600,
        "desiredCool": 840,
        "desiredHumidity": 36,
        "desiredDehumidity": 60,
        "desiredFanMode": "auto"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": {
    "code": 0,
    "message": ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `UrlFetchApp` doesn't support sending payload using the get method as a query string.  I assume this is correct design for `UrlFetchApp` and [poor design on the part of the Ecobee API](http://developer.ecobee.com/api/topics/non-standard-rest-api).  I made a kluge workaround by sending the JSON in a query string myself as follows.

```
var URL = 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat?body='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(payload));
```